# Django, edit button with modal form does not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-views

In one of my django app I have set the following architecture:

```
#models.py
    class Income(models.Model):
        price = models.DecimalField()
        quantity = models.DecimalField()
        date=models.DateField()

# forms.py
    class IncomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Income
            fields = "__all__"

#views.py
def income_(request):
    elements = Income.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = IncomeForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             new_input = form.save()
    else :
       form = IncomeForm()
       elements = Income.objects.all()

    context= {
       'form': form,
       'elements':elements,
            }
    return render(request, "income/income.html", context)

def edit_income(request):
    pk = request.GET.get('pk')
    object = get_object_or_404(Income, pk = pk)
    form = IncomeForm(instance=object)
    return render(request, 'edit_income.html', {
        'object': object,
        'pk': pk,
        'form': form,
        })
```

After that I have set the following urlspatterns:

```
path('magazzino/gestionemagazzino/', views.income_, name ='gestione_magazzino'),
path('magazzino/edit_modal/<int:materiale_pk/>', views.edit_income, name='edit_income')
```

In my income.html file I have set the following

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
 <form id="" method="post">                    
   <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
       {{form.quantity|as_crispy_field}}
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
       {{form.price|as_crispy_field}}
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
      {{form.date|as_crispy_field}}
   </div>
</div>
```

After that I have created a table that list all data filled and in the last column I have set the following button:

```
<button id="myBtn" data-target="#myModal"> </button>
```

Now I want to create a button for each row that open a modal form that give me the possibility to modify the specific data for each id dataset.

I have tried to perform the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myBtn").click(function(){
    var pk = $(this).data('pid')
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
  });
  $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(event){
    var modal = $(this)
    var pk = $(this).data('pid')
    $.ajax({
        data: {'pk': pk},
        url: "{% url 'edit_income' %}",
        context: document.body,
        error: function(response, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        modal.html(response);
    });
  });
});
```

That open the following edit_income.html:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <form action="{% url 'edit_paper' pk=object.pk %}" method="post" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Income</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{form|crispy}}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save changes" />
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </form>
</div>
```

But if I press on the button does not work nothing. Where is the issue?

Comment: Which button is not working the save changes in Modal or you are not able to open Modal ?

Comment: What i get is that you are trying to edit each field individually and you want to place button in front of each row to edit. Post some errors you are getting.Also Your view for edit do not have an arg to get the passed data from client side as get.`def edit_income` don't have any validation and no save call to save the changes.The Save calls and required things exists in `def income` which is not the endpoint for the form in ajax call.There are many mistakes.